# Is there a better way to double escape (or escape twice) user input in BASH than calling printf twice?

Tags: bash, printf, escaping

This script will read an old and a new value from the user and then use sed to find and replace them in a file.  For example if I entered T*T*z and B*B*z it would look for T\*T\*z in the file and replace with B\*B\*z.  It works but I've been trying to make this more concise.

I don't have any need for the intermediate variables $ESC_OLD_PW and $ESC_NEW_PW.  Is there a more ***sensible*** way to do this?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    read -sp "Old:" OLD_PW && echo
    read -sp "New:" NEW_PW && echo

    # Add escape characters to what user entered
    printf -v ESC_OLD_PW "%q" "${OLD_PW}"
    printf -v ESC_NEW_PW "%q" "${NEW_PW}"

    # Escape again for the sed evaluation.
    printf -v ESC_ESC_OLD_PW "%q" "${ESC_OLD_PW}"
    printf -v ESC_ESC_NEW_PW "%q" "${ESC_NEW_PW}"

    sed -i -e s/"${ESC_ESC_OLD_PW}"/"${ESC_ESC_NEW_PW}"/g $1
```

I've tried the following:

```
    ~$ OLD_PW="T*T*z"
    ~$ printf "%q" $OLD_PW | xargs printf "%q"
    printf: %q: invalid conversion specification
    ~$
```

And I've tried many variations on piping things into printf...  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intermediate variable-free:

```
sed -i -e "s/$(printf '%q' $(printf '%q' $OLD_PW))/$(printf '%q' $(printf '%q' $NEW_PW))/g" $1
```

Comment: AHA!  printf '%q' $(printf '%q' $OLD_PW)  THX!!
xargs fails me again.  or did I fail it?  it is such a trying relationship...

Comment: @Jeff, the reason your xargs doesn't work is that GNU printf doesn't support %q.  GNU bash's built-in printf does, though. This is a bit odd, but you should keep in mind %q is non-standard.

Comment: @Jeff: That's correct. In your last example the first `printf` is calling Bash's, but `xargs` calls the external `/usr/bin/printf`.

Comment: How crazy... so with xargs you'd need something like xargs bash -c 'printf "%q" "$@"', and possibly extra crazy quoting.

Luckily I use $(cmd) instead of xargs mostly (except when the output of cmd is too long).